# Can I use proper division concept for checking prime numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I am doing Problem 95 on Project Euler website [here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=95). The problem description stated that proper divisors of a number are all the divisors excluding the number itself. I want to know whether this concept can be used to check a prime number. Specifically, if the only proper divisor of a number (for example 13) is 1, can I, by all means, state that the number is a prime number?

Comment: Yes, you are right. A prime number has only two divisors, $1$ and itself.

Comment: Can I still use this concept for big prime numbers?

Comment: Prime numbers still have only two divisors, whether big or small in magnitude.

Comment: For big possible primes, usually [Miller-Rabin Test](https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/164) is used.

Comment: p is prime if and only if its only proper divisor is $1$. This doesn't depend on the size of the prime. However, this is not at all a useful or efficient primality check. It's quite literally the definition of a prime number.

Comment: So, basically this concept is not efficient in computation time for big prime numbers?

Comment: @infinitylord Ok, thank you for your answer

Comment: @AkhmadZaki: It's hard to even answer that because you are asking "is the definition of a prime number a useful way to check for prime numbers." All primality checkers rely on the fact that $1$ is its only proper divisor, but you need to develop further techniques to increase efficiency.

Comment: @Rohan Thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: @swoopin_swallow Thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: @infinitylord Is it possible to do prime checking algorithm for very big prime numbers (contain thousands of digits) using only single machine (laptop or PC)?

Comment: You can also use "Sieve of Eratosthenes" to find the prime numbers since they are bounded with 1 million in the question. It is also an interesting algorithm that you can use in later questions as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, absolutely. It may not be the most computationally efficient way, nor the most philosophically elegant, but it may make more sense to you.

For the most part, you can match the divisors in pairs. For example, is 729 prime? It's not. We see that:

- $1 \times 729 = 729$ (but you already knew that)
- $3 \times 243 = 729$
- $9 \times 81 = 729$
- $27 \times 27 = 729$

731 is not prime either, since $17 \times 43 = 731$. But 733 is prime:

- $1 \times 733 = 733$ (obviously)
- $3 \times 244 = 732$, not 733
- $5 \times 147 = 735$, not 733
- ...
- $25 \times 29 = 725$, not 733
- $27 \times 27 = 729$, not 733

Answer (score 1):

You can cut your work down quite a bit.  If $n$ is a positive integer, and if $n$ contains no proper divisors that are between 2 and $\sqrt{n}$, then $n$ must be prime.

The reason why you only need to check integers between 2 and $\sqrt{n}$ is because $n = \sqrt{n}*\sqrt{n}$, and so if $n = ab$ with $a,b$ integers both greater than 1, then at least one of $a$ or $b$ is less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Another useful fact is that, if $p > 3$ is a prime number, then $p^2 - 1$ is a multiple of $24$. It won't tell you if a number *is* prime, but is a nice trick for showing that quite a lot of numbers aren't without needing to do excessive calculations.